# arara: fallback directive if no directives specified

Tags: arara

### Question

Is it possible to tell `arara` to use a default directive when no directive is specified in the file, e.g. to run `pdflatex` twice?

### Background

I often get LaTeX-files from other people, and every time I need to add some `arara`-rules before I can typeset them. It would be very nice if this process could be automated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is "no". `arara`'s core element are the rules and the specification of the rules inside your main document.

If you want to compile your friend's file with `arara` you can provide your main testing file like:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\input{file-of-friend}
```

However I think most editors allow the switching between different compilation steps very easy. So if you want to compile with `pdflatex` you can choose `pdflatex`.

In my opinion there is no need for such an implementation.